# Best Google Charts API tutorial for user?

Tags: google-visualization

Would like to learn the Google Charts API, starting from a user perspective. Want to start from the ground up.

What is the best set of tutorials for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the widest variety of examples (especially for a user perspective) can be found at ["50 Google Charts Tricks for Your Next Classroom Presentation"](http://www.collegeathome.com/blog/2008/06/05/50-cool-things-you-can-do-with-google-charts-api/).  Although some of the examples linked there are still uses of Google Charts in some web-based systems, there seem to be a good number of practical tutorials for general use as well.